# New email server (OpenBSD) not receiving emails sent from Gmail - but is receiving from other sources

Tags: email, gmail, tls1.3, openbsd, opensmtpd

I followed Derek Sivers' guide to tech independence, spun up an OpenBSD server, and followed various steps to provision an email server on it.   From this server, I am able to send emails to various domains - gmail, hey.com, proton.me.   I am able to receive email from Hey and Proton and from a few MS Exchange accounts I've tested, but I am not receiving email sent from gmail.   I get a "delivery incomplete" message with this error message below.

TLS Negotiation failed: FAILED_PRECONDITION: starttls error (71): 22102848438272:error:10000417:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER:third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592:SSL alert number 47

Looking for help to solve this.

I'm pretty inexperienced with this, so my troubleshooting has revolved around trying to find a relevant answer through search and exploring some of the tools in MX Toolbox and SSL labs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of answering my own question.  I originally had my domain set up through Cloudflare with some custom SSL/TLS settings that were apparently conflicting with the new server.